# Postgres "relation not found" after running a pg_restore with a Django management command

Tags: django, postgresql, kubernetes, cron

I'm creating a test database that needs to be sanitized from customer data and needs to stay in sync with our production database. So I have a cronjob in Kubernetes that does a `pg_dump`, `pg_restore` and then will run a Django management command to clean the database.

The dump and restore work well. I can connect to it via `psql` and see all tables. The problem is that the management command is failing to find a table relation (literally the first row in the Django script) and if I run a `psql` right after the restore, it also doesn't find the table, even though I print all the tables to make sure.

All this is done through a docker container that has a shell script that basically does the dump, restore and runs the command (unsuccessfully) and the cronjob is connected to the database via a Azure pgbouncer (that's why `localhost`).

This is what I have so far:

```sh
psql -h localhost -U user -d postgres -c "\i recreate_db.sql"
```

- `recreate_db.sql`: I use this script to close connections, drop and recreate database for simplicity:

```sql
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)
    FROM pg_stat_activity
    WHERE datname = 'my_db';
DROP DATABASE my_db;
CREATE DATABASE my_db;
```

- This works and show all the tables:

```sh
psql -h localhost -U user -d my_db -c "SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables;"
```

- This fails because the relation does not exist (same error I see in the django command)

```sh
psql -h localhost -U user -d my_db -c "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myapp_sometable;"
ERROR:  relation "myapp_sometable" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myapp_sometable;
```

Other things I've tried:

- I changed the shell script to be just a long sleep, did a `kubectl exec` in the pod and ran the Django management command from there and it also works!
- Checked all database credentials
- I have tripled checked all env variables to make sure they are correct
- I tried to run a docker container locally connected to the database to run the same shell script and it works nicely

Does anybody have some insights here?

Comment: You did everything but the thing you should have done: `psql -h localhost -U user -d my_db` then `\d` in `psql`. My bet is the table is not actually spelled `myapp_sometable` in the database and is either  mixed or upper case and needs double quoting.

Comment: The table name is picked up from the ORM that Django generates so no way to get the name wrong. Another thing I tried after the post is run the Cronjob to to the dump and restore only. Then I run it again with the management command and it works. My guess is that there’s some sort of race condition when running the command right after the pg_restore